# AudioKit 5 delay time - causing digital click when changing

Tags: ios, swift, delay, audiokit

I'm building a synth using AudioKit and I’m trying to change the delay  time with slider but it's causing a digital click when changing.
I tried also the Cookbook of delay but didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
    @IBAction func delayTimeSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
        mySynth.setDelayTime(time: AUValue(sender.value / 1000))
    }
```

```
    func setDelayTime(time: AUValue){
        delay.time = time
    }
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,
David

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently it’s a  problem in apple’s code...